# prove that in a complete oriented graph there is triangle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

prove that in a full complete oriented graph there is a triangle .

I tried to use something like red and blue edges. But I can't figure out how to choose directions of edges and which colour is every edge.

Comment: What about the complete directed graph with one vertex and no edges? Surely that graph doesn't contain a "triangle".

Comment: Are you working with [tournaments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)#:~:text=A%20tournament%20is%20a%20directed,in%20an%20undirected%20complete%20graph.)? Also, what do you mean by triangle? Do you mean a directed 3-cycle?

Comment: This is only true if you know there is at least one cycle in the graph.

Comment: when does complete oriented graph have a cycle? And  problem says that there aren't any vertexes without edges. Also I don't know what problem means by triangle but if it was not directed 3-cycle,  the problem would not make sense so I think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by a "triangle" you mean a (directed) $3-$cycle, then this is false. Line the $n$ vertices up from left to right and make every edge a forward (left to right) edge. This tournament clearly does not have a $3-$cycle.

EDIT : As @Brandon pointed out in the comments, the statement is true if the graph has at least one cycle.

To see this, suppose we're given the cycle $u_k\rightarrow u_{k+1}\rightarrow u_{k+2}\cdots \rightarrow u_{k+m}\rightarrow u_{k}$, arrange the vertices of the cycle from left to right (the last edge in the sequence is a back edge).

If we have a forward edge $u_{k+1}\rightarrow u_{k+m}$ then we are done, since we then have the 3-cycle $u_k\rightarrow u_{k+1}\rightarrow u_{k+m}\rightarrow u_k$.

Otherwise, we have a smaller cycle $u_{k+1}\rightarrow u_{k+2}\cdots \rightarrow u_{k+m}\rightarrow u_{k+1}$

Continuing this reasoning, one can also see that unless all the edges from $u_{k+m}$ to the vertices $u_{k+2}, u_{k+3}\cdots$ in the cycle are back edges, you'll eventually find a 3-cycle. But if all of them are back edges, then we have the following $3-$cycle --

$u_{k+m-2}\rightarrow u_{k+m-1}\rightarrow u_{k+m}\rightarrow u_{k+m-2}$.

So we're done.

Comment: if the graph is full , can we say that there's a cycle passing to all vertexes?

Comment: I know but in my problem graph is full

Comment: @DeltaAccount What do you mean by full?

Answer (score 0):

I will proove it using induction.
**Base:** For graph of size $3$ it is true.
**Hypothesis:** Assume for size $k$ it is true.
**Induction:** In graph of size $k+1$ consider any three consicutive vertices of cycle. Let $a, b, c$ such vertices with orientation $(a-b-c)$.
Case 1: If edge $ac$ has orientation $(a-c)$ it creates cycle with $k-1$ vertices and according to hypothesis this cycle contains a triangle.
Note: This cycle does not contain $b$. i.e. $cycle-b$
Case 2: If edge ac has orientation $(c-a)$ then $abc$ creates triangle.

Answer (score 0):

An oriented complete graph (a.k.a. *tournament*) does not necessarily contain a directed $3$-cycle, but the counterexamples are very special.

Suppose your oriented complete graph contains no directed $3$-cycle. For vertices $a$ and $b$, define $a\lt b$ to mean that there is an arc from $a$ to $b$. Since the graph is complete and has no directed $3$-cycles, whenever we have $a\lt b$ and $b\lt c$ we must also have $a\lt c$. That is, $\lt$ is a transitive relation, and therefore it is a linear order relation, the other required properties being obvious.

So the only oriented complete graphs without directed $3$-cycles are linear orders (a.k.a. *transitive tournaments*), which have no directed cycles at all.